# Equivalence of different definitions for chemical potential

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-potential

In some books, the [chemical potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential) is defined in term of the Gibbs energy as
$$
\mu_i \equiv \left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial n_i}  \right)_{P,T,n_j}
$$
where $n_j$ indicates all mole numbers except the *i*th species mole number.

In other books, it is defined in term of the Helmholtz energy as

$$
\mu_i \equiv \left( \frac{\partial A}{\partial n_i}  \right)_{V,T,n_j}
$$

Looking up at the Physics Stack Exchange, I could also find:

$$
\mu_i \equiv \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial n_i}  \right)_{S,V,n_j}
$$

And I suppose (by analogy) that one may also define it as

$$
\mu_i \equiv \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial n_i}  \right)_{S,P,n_j}
$$

Are all these definitions equivalent? Why?

Or they give rise to different quantities and one should be consistent when using one definition or the other?

I have tried to work out one definition from the other using thermodynamics identities but I could not make it out.

Comment: They are just simplifications depending on what is taken to be constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the second TD law:
$$
\tag 1 dU(S,V) = TdS - pdV,
$$
In case of variable number of particles it is modified by the adding $\mu dn$ term to the right side:
$$
dU(S, V, n) = TdS - pdV + \mu d n.
$$
The other TD potentials are related with $U$ by Legendre transformation with variables $T, S, p, V$, but not $\mu$ or $n$. So it's obviously that the relation
$$
\mu = \left( \frac{\partial Y (n, X)}{\partial n}\right)_{X = const}
$$
is true for all of four TD potentials $Y$.

Comment: Thanks! I had to read other sources to fully understand the answer, but your mention to Legendre transformation showed me the way. Reviewing "ܶNonnatural derivatives" was also important. The paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1147 by Zia, Redish and McKay was very useful for understanding the Legendre transformation.